# VNC grey screen (Ubuntu 16.04, TightVNC, Xfce4)

Tags: 16.04, xfce, vnc, tightvncserver

I've been using VNC for many years but I don't know why this happens sometimes. With a new Ubuntu 16.04 machine, I first tried using Vino. It worked well, but I decided it is rather slow, so I decided to use TightVNC with the Xfce4 window manger. However I get this "grey screen" (I have experienced it before couple of times..) again.
My `xstartup` is :

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
startxfce4 &
```

and the log file is :

```
24/08/18 09:47:09 Xvnc version TightVNC-1.3.10
24/08/18 09:47:09 Copyright (C) 2000-2009 TightVNC Group
24/08/18 09:47:09 Copyright (C) 1999 AT&T Laboratories Cambridge
24/08/18 09:47:09 All Rights Reserved.
24/08/18 09:47:09 See http://www.tightvnc.com/ for information on TightVNC
24/08/18 09:47:09 Desktop name 'X' (kimchan:1)
24/08/18 09:47:09 Protocol versions supported: 3.3, 3.7, 3.8, 3.7t, 3.8t
24/08/18 09:47:09 Listening for VNC connections on TCP port 5901
Font directory '/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/' not found - ignoring
Font directory '/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/' not found - ignoring
/usr/bin/startxfce4: X server already running on display :1
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":1".
xfce4-session: Another session manager is already running

24/08/18 09:48:08 Got connection from client 129.254.132.39
24/08/18 09:48:08 Using protocol version 3.8
24/08/18 09:48:12 Full-control authentication passed by 129.254.132.39
24/08/18 09:48:12 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 16
24/08/18 09:48:12 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 22
24/08/18 09:48:12 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 21
24/08/18 09:48:12 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 15
24/08/18 09:48:12 Using zlib encoding for client 129.254.132.39
24/08/18 09:48:12 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -314
24/08/18 09:48:12 Enabling full-color cursor updates for client 129.254.132.39
24/08/18 09:48:12 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -223
24/08/18 09:48:12 Pixel format for client 129.254.132.39:
24/08/18 09:48:12   32 bpp, depth 24, little endian
24/08/18 09:48:12   true colour: max r 255 g 255 b 255, shift r 16 g 8 b 0
24/08/18 09:48:12   no translation needed
24/08/18 09:48:12 Using raw encoding for client 129.254.132.39
24/08/18 09:48:12 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 22
24/08/18 09:48:12 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 21
24/08/18 09:48:12 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 16
24/08/18 09:48:12 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 15
24/08/18 09:48:12 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -314
24/08/18 09:48:12 Enabling full-color cursor updates for client 129.254.132.39
24/08/18 09:48:12 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -223
24/08/18 09:48:12 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 16
24/08/18 09:48:12 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 22
24/08/18 09:48:12 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 21
24/08/18 09:48:12 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 15
24/08/18 09:48:12 Using zlib encoding for client 129.254.132.39
24/08/18 09:48:12 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -314
24/08/18 09:48:12 Enabling full-color cursor updates for client 129.254.132.39
24/08/18 09:48:12 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -223
```

What is wrong here? Is `X server already running on display :1` an error? And how about `"RANDR" missing on display:1`?  And what are those many `ignoring unknown encoding` messages?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I found https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=180965

and changed my xstartup to

```
#!/bin/sh
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
startxfce4 &
```

and it works!

Comment: this works for me xubuntu 18.04

Comment: Also works on Debian Buster 10 with XFCE DE.

Comment: Caused buffer overflows for me on 18.04

Comment: works with debian 9 (stretch)

Comment: Working on 16.04 running on Orange Pi

Comment: Worked for me as well

Comment: Worked on Xubuntu 20.04!

Comment: Debian 12 not working, unless you install package `dbus-x11`. Then it works fine.

Comment: This solution works with XFCE, XUbuntu 22.04

Answer (score 2):

Working config for Gnome

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Config requires following packages:
# gnome-panel nautilus gnome-terminal metacity
#


export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1

unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
    
[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey

gnome-session &
gnome-panel &

metacity &
gnome-terminal &
```

Answer (score 1):

Following the other upvoted answer, I simply put:

```
#!/bin/sh
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
startxfce4 &
```

in my `~/.vnc/xstartup` file and I was able to connect locally.  Additionally, I had to edit `/etc/vnc/conf` adding the line:

```
$localhost = "no";
```

to let other machines on my private network connect to the tigervnc server (as opposed to only `localhost` clients).

Answer (score 1):

None of the above worked for me.  I found a suggestion on https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/TigerVNC#Recommended_security_settings

Try this:

```
vncserver -geometry ... -depth 24
```

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure you have **'dbus-x11'** installed

```
sudo apt-get install dbus-x11
```

According to [packages.debian.org](https://packages.debian.org/en/sid/dbus-x11):
This package contains the dbus-launch utility, which automatically launches one D-Bus session bus per X11 display per user. If the dbus-user-session package is also installed, it takes precedence over this package.

Comment: Please add a reference why this is needed.

Comment: Dec 01 2023 all suggestions failed. Only after installing `dbus-x11` it was possible to have a working TightVNC (Debian Server, Win10 Client). To make the solution complete , keeping or not the `&` after `startxfce4` command makes no difference, but you have to make use of `unset SESSION_MANAGER` and `unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS`.  Just to mention that if screen sharing is required with the existed user, usually logged in at X screen `:0` , then you need to install the package `x11vnc`. In that case you "start" the vnc server by simply running `x11vnc`. ( use port `::5900` on client)

Answer (score 0):

su -l username -c "(export DISPLAY=:5; dbus-launch --exit-with-session; vncserver -geometry 1792x899 -depth 24 :5)"

The command "dbus-launch --exit-with-session" sets dbus variables to be specific to the user running vncserver, otherwise it might pick them up from somewhere else or not have them set at all.
  DBUS_SESSION_BUS_PID=31898
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1003/bus

These need to be set correctly or you will get a blank screen or permission denied.
For example
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1003/bus
Where 1003 is the id of the user.

Comment: This already has an accepted answer. I do not see that your answer adds anything.

Comment: Because the accepted answer did not work for me.  It only worked if starting vncserver as root user.  If you wanted to start vncserver as a different user with those important environment variables unset, then it would fail with permission errors or a blank screen.

Comment: Also the next post from coder1 is also correct, you need dbus-x11 or dbus-user-session package installed

Comment: @AndyFlanagan in my setup , `dbus-user-session` was installed but the problem was only solved after installing `dbus-x11`